# Conditional convergent serie question

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $x_{n}$ is a conditionally convergent series how can I prove that for any $\epsilon >0$ there exist infinitely many positve and negative terms such that $|x_{n}|<\epsilon$.

Comment: If the series is conditionally convergent, there is at least one ordering of the terms that converges, and to converge the terms of the series must tend to 0. If there is a reordering that makes it diverge to $\infty$, there must be infinite positive terms; to make it possible to get a finite value the infinite positive terms must be offset by infinite negative ones. Details are for you to fill in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that for some $\epsilon > 0$ there are only finitely many negative terms such that $|x_n| < \epsilon$. Since $\sum x_n$ is convergent, $\lim x_n = 0$, so there are only finitely many $n$ such that $|x_n| \geq \epsilon$, so starting from some point, absolute values of the terms are smaller then $\epsilon$. Since there are only finitely many negative terms with absolute value smaller than $\epsilon$, starting from some further point, all terms are positive (because from some point terms are smaller then $\epsilon$, and there are finitely many negative such terms), so the series is absolutely convergent.